# box-sizing:border-box has wrong height

Tags: css

I have a page with a carousel of photos. But the thumbs are in a box that is too high.
I see that that is because of the box-sizing:border-box property. How can I change that? When I set it to none, all the images at the right side float to the bottom, so that isn't the solution.
Here is my page: http://www.tina-turner.nl/beyondchildren.htm

Comment: The load time of this website is amazing. Amazingly slow, that is.

Comment: This question will become useless to future visitors once you fix your page. Therefore, this kind of questions are not allowed in StackOverflow. Fix it including the code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself, or otherwise the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of the 2 divs

```
.es-carousel-wrapper { height: 180px; }
.es-carousel { height: 150px; }
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! Really appreciated.
As for my site loading slowly, I use the Maxcdn, have my images as small as possible, so I don't see what more I can do.
Johanna